Cross origin redirect sign-in on Google Chrome M115+ is no longer supported, and will stop working on June 24, 2024
I am developing a gym application, consisting of two separate apps: one for administrators and another for members. User registration is facilitated through Google Firebase authentication using email and password. Today, I noticed an error message on my project panel regarding cross-origin redirect sign-ins.
Currently, I do not utilize any sign-in or sign-in with Facebook options on the login pages of either app, and both apps are connected to a single Firebase project. Should I disregard this message since my login process does not involve redirects from other websites, or is it necessary to implement changes to comply with the new policies?
Currently, I do not utilize any sign-in or sign-in with Facebook options on the login pages of either app, and both apps are connected to a single Firebase project. Should I disregard this message since my login process does not involve redirects from other websites, or is it necessary to implement changes to comply with the new policies?

You have no issue if you are using sign in with email and password.

Use Sign-in flow popup instead of redirect in the firebaseui config
'signInFlow': 'popup', // default is 'redirect'


If you have used the method "signInWithRedirect()" or any other similar it will have an effect when using chrome. Otherwise I think it should be fine.

Try to run App on published mode . While i was creating basic app i face same error . By running app on published mode it work for me.

Remember to add the SHA-256 fingerprint to your Firebase project, then redownload the service.json file and add it to the app directory.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth
for more details use the link above.
thanks, i hope it will be helpful.
